# How to make images change a little quicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My code works just fine but for some reason when you click on the play button it takes a bit longer to switch over to the pause sign, and occasionally it takes a bit longer for the pause button to go to the play button. I also have one more question, when you click on the rain and beach icon there's a blue square border that I didn't remember putting, how do you remove it?
Thanks, Love2code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meditation App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;

        }
        .app{
            height:100vh;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .time-select,.sound-picker,.player-container{
            height:80%;
            flex:1;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .player-container{
            position:relative;
        }
        .player-container svg{
            position:absolute;
            height:50%;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            pointer-events:none;

        }

        .time-display{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:10%;
            color:white;
            font-size:50px;
        }
        video{
            position:fixed;
            top:0%;
            left:0%;
            width:100%;
            z-index:-10;

        }
        .time-select button, 
        .sound-picker button{
            color:white;
            width:30%;
            height:10%;
            background:none;
            border:2px solid white;
            cursor:pointer;
            border-radius:5px;
            font-size:20px;
            transition:all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .time-select button:hover{
            color:black;
            background:white;

        }
        .sound-picker button{
            border:none;
            height:120px;
            width:120px;
            border-radius:50%;
        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
            background:#4972a1;
   

        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
            background:#a14f49;
        }
  .sound-picker:focus{
  outline: none;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="vid-container">
            <video Loop>
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"/>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="player-container">
            <audio class="song">
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1"></source>
            </audio>
         <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1" class="play-container" alt="">
        <svg class="track-outline"
        width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="moving-outline"
    width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#018EBA" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
<h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
</div>
<div class="sound-picker">
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8BspYTV/rain-1.png"></button>
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k9nauf2ffyvfuu/beach.mp3?raw=1"
    data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsdd86bxmax32jp/beach.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/T0xw4k7/sun-umbrella.png"></button>


</div>





</body>
<script>
  const app = () => {
        const song = document.querySelector(".song");
        const play = document.querySelector(".play-container");
        const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
        const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container video");

        //Sounds
        const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");
        //Time Display
        const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
        //Get length of the outside
        const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
        //Duration
        let fakeDuration = 600;

        outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;
  
  //play sounds
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
   checkPlaying(song);
  });
  //stop and play the sounds
  const checkPlaying = song =>{
    if(song.paused){
   song.play();
   video.play();
   play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zvnjkebwt1sjgq/download%20%283%29.svg?raw=1';
  }else{
   song.pause();
   video.pause();
   play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1';
  }
  }
    };  
    app();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're not using a CSS reset, the "blue box" is probably the browser's default styling with an outline for an active element.

Comment: Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: On a quick glance it seems you should probably be looking at some asynchronous-loader (aka AJAX) to handle the downloading of your media files. This would help minimize how much the media files affect the UI. Also, if you strategically used some delays or buffering, this could help smooth out the experience... ie have the button change state right away and show some kind of spinner (communicating to the user something is happening) while operations happen on the media file (local or downloading). Only begin media playback when things are ready, and fade it in accordingly.

Comment: It seems when you click the button the browser is loading an image source and before it loads Pause image won't appear. To solve this issue you have to preload images. To achieve such result you can either add images in HTML and hide or use `New Image()` construction to preload using Javascript and then bind onLoad event and then pass the Callback function to do later work.

Comment: Here's a tidied-up version of your code with fixed playback icon change: https://jsfiddle.net/jvfz5Lst/15/. Not addressing all that is wrong about the original source code. Other respondents are right saying that loading assets dynamically from DropBox adds overhead you are experiencing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your SVGs are remotely sourced, it takes a bit of time to download them. I've created two hidden images with the remote sources. This will download these and have them ready in your cash for when you need them. I've also changed the sequence of when you switch the source path to come before you play the video.
I've set all elements to have an outline of none to take away the blue border when clicking on the image.

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play-container");
  const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
  const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container video");

  //Sounds
  const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");
  //Time Display
  const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
  //Get length of the outside
  const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
  //Duration
  let fakeDuration = 600;

  outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

  //play sounds
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });
  //stop and play the sounds
  const checkPlaying = song => {
    if (song.paused) {
      play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zvnjkebwt1sjgq/download%20%283%29.svg?raw=1';
      song.play();
      video.play();

    } else {
      play.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1';
      song.pause();
      video.pause();

    }
  }
};
app();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.time-select,
.sound-picker,
.player-container {
  height: 80%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-container {
  position: relative;
}

.player-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.time-display {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.time-select button,
.sound-picker button {
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.time-select button:hover {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

.sound-picker button {
  border: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sound-picker button:nth-child(1) {
  background: #4972a1;
}

.sound-picker button:nth-child(2) {
  background: #a14f49;
}

.sound-picker:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zvnjkebwt1sjgq/download%20%283%29.svg?raw=1" style="display:none;">
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1" style="display:none;">
<div class="app">
  <div class="vid-container">
    <video Loop>
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"/>
            </video>
  </div>
  <div class="time-select">
    <button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
    <button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
    <button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
  </div>
  <div class="player-container">
    <audio class="song">
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1"></source>
            </audio>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unx3knosmefedk/download%20%281%29.svg?raw=1" class="play-container" alt="">
    <svg class="track-outline" width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="moving-outline" width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#018EBA" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
    <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="sound-picker">
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8BspYTV/rain-1.png"></button>
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k9nauf2ffyvfuu/beach.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsdd86bxmax32jp/beach.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/T0xw4k7/sun-umbrella.png"></button>


  </div>
```

Comment: And, alternatively, one could place the SVG contents directly in the HTML for even quicker UI loading time.

Comment: Yip, that would be even better